# Execute long running SQL query even when client process is killed

Tags: .net, sql-server

I call a stored procedure in my application, which takes a long time deleting records in the database. I realized if I kill my application process during this execution, that the deletion of records stops.

I tried `SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery` and `SqlCommand.BeginExecuteNonQuery`, but both have the same effect.

Is there a way to start a sql query which executes to the end no matter what happens to the client?

Update:
In this case I want the process to run asynchronously, and preferably to be parametrized.

Comment: Why it takes long time? Are you deleting millions of records? or are you deleting records in a huge table? There is no way to continue execution of a query after the connection is terminated.

Comment: So there is no 'fire and forget'?

Comment: No, there is not unless you execute a job

Answer (score 2):

You can add the procedure to a SQL Server job and execute the SQL Server job instead of the procedure.

```
USE msdb ;
GO

EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'Weekly Sales Data Backup' ;
GO
```

Comment: How can you answer the question w/o knowing detail of the issue? If DELETE happens during data entry, he cannot use  sql-job.

Comment: Why you think there is an issue? He justs wants to start something which would not get killed when connection drops. Offcourse you can start the sql job when somerhing else is importing data. Thats why we have a lockinh mechanism. Ok concurrency can get a problem... but thats not thw point right now.

Comment: I mentioned the reason in my comment. OP says he has an application and in his app, he call a procedure to delete records, I assume after deleting the record, his code is doing something else, so this cannot be asynchronous. His app has to wait until records are deleted and then continue the execution the app code. He is not clear about the situation and any answer might be Right/Wrong/Misleading or Confusing.

Comment: I just think the OP doesnt want a time out or a network issue which will breaks his connection and will cause a rollback. I realle dont have a clue why starting a job is wrong in this situation. Maybe its better that the sql agent needs to start it but still i dont see a problem at all